# How to fix "CURL return invalid headers" in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get content-type and content-length of an image. Response are different on localhost/browser and LAMP/LEMP. How can I get true response as same as localhost/browser?

Here is [an image URL](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/DXIeeda-C_xS6xqUiVnUnx6vMOkNmahpW0TypbGdx8Cy3q2L5ds9YUyfMroVQo4ERxw8MQyqY0A) that I've tried.

Response on localhost:

```
HTTP Code: 200
Type: image/png
Length: 1017
```

Response on LAMP/LEMP server:

```
HTTP Code: 200
Type: image/jpeg
Length: 4232
```

Here is my code

```
$imageUrl = 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/DXIeeda-C_xS6xqUiVnUnx6vMOkNmahpW0TypbGdx8Cy3q2L5ds9YUyfMroVQo4ERxw8MQyqY0A'; //type = png
$imageInfo = getInfo($imageUrl);
print_r($imageInfo);

function getInfo($requestUrl) {
    $handle = curl_init($requestUrl);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET', 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $type = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $length = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($handle);
    return 'HTTP Code: ' . $code . "\n" . 'Type: ' . $type . "\n" . 'Length: ' . $length;
}
```

I expect the output of header response to be

> Content-type: image/png

But the actual output is

> Content-type: image/jpeg

Comment: That is probably a result of _content negotiation_. Try and send an `Accept` header expressing your preferences.

Comment: Yep, this is only a test request.